# Kubernetes secretRefKey not supported in V1.2 Atomic Host RHEL?

Tags: kubernetes, rhel

When I create this Pod from http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/secrets/:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secret-env-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: mycontainer
      image: redis
      env:
        - name: SECRET_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysecret
              key: username
        - name: SECRET_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysecret
              key: password
  restartPolicy: Never
```

The I get this error:

```
error validating "rc.yml": error validating data: [field fieldRef: is required, found invalid field secretKeyRef for v1.EnvVarSource]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

I am using version 1.2 latest release by Atomic Host RHEL:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.0", GitCommit:"738b7603b042dcda7a5ba419ab0e7f40a617080c", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.0", GitCommit:"738b7603b042dcda7a5ba419ab0e7f40a617080c", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Is there something wrong with the RHEL's Kubernetes distribution in Atomic Host?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Kubernetes caches api version stuff in ~/.kube and we recently upgraded to stable V1.2. This solved the issue:

```
rm -rf ~/.kube
```

Comment: please don't delete the Kube config without backup